# Ansible - Syntax to point a variable to a variable in a vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

Trying to use an ansible-vault to hold a sensitive password, but I can't find the right syntax to retrieve it in a playbook.

The [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices-for-variables-and-vaults) mentions (Emphasis mine):

> Next, copy all of the sensitive variables over to the vault file and prefix these variables with vault_. **You should adjust the variables in the vars file to point to the matching vault_ variables using jinja2 syntax**, and ensure that the vault file is vault encrypted.

I created the vault, but I am really not familiar enough with jinja2 within yml to find the right syntax for the vars.yml file.

Anyone can help with the syntax on how to point variable 'X' in the playbook to take the value of the variable "vault_X" that is in the vault file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not try to use import_vars module to import vars stored in the encrypted file into your playbook? Then in the playbook itself you reference them as you would normally do. You just need to add

> --ask-vault-pass

when running your playbook.

Comment: That's how I ended doing it 5 mins ago.  I was trying to use the "best practice" described, but I just can't make it work, so I did an include_vars on the file itself and ask-vault-pass on the commandline.  But I'm still curious to learn how to do it with jinja in a yml file.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I was curious about the same thing. I couldn't find it in the Ansible documentation so I worked out a solution by following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-protect-sensitive-ansible-data-on-ubuntu-16-04) which had more information than the docs.

The jinja2 syntax is: `"{{ [var_name] }}"` (with quotes). What this looks like in practice:

for a vault.yml file with contents:

```
---
#vault.yml
vault_ex_pw: password
```

in the same directory as your vars.yml file, the syntax is:

```
---
#vars.yml
ex_pw: "{{ vault_ex_pw }}"
```

This should give you the result you wanted, which I believe is the "best practice" the Ansible docs were referencing. Note that you will need to reference these var files somewhere in your playbook so that the jinja2 variable pointing works (otherwise you'll receive an error: `The error was: 'vault_ex_pw' is undefined`). One way to do this is:

```
#ex_playbook.yml
[your code here]
  vars_files:
    - /path/to/ansible/directory/group_vars/vars.yml
    - /path/to/ansible/directory/group_vars/vault.yml
```